# Control theory in PLC (programmable logic controller)?

Tags: control, control-system

What is the control theory of PLCs (programmable logic controller)?

PLCs fall in category of linear control or non linear control?

Comment: Far too broad a question.

Comment: "PLC" is just another name for "digital computer", so what do you think?

Comment: They're programmable so you can use whatever theory you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A **programmable** logic controller does what you tell it to.  So you can make it **implement** a linear control rule, or you can make it **implement** a non-linear control rule.

By itself, a PLC isn't described by one control theory or another.